# Techniques to obain the infimum of a function

Tags: convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I am studying convex optimization from Boyd. In the problem 5.22 I need to find the dual function of the optimization problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & e^{-x} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \frac{x^2}{y} \leq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I found that the dual function is $$g(x,y,\lambda) = \inf_{x,y >0} (e^{-x} -\lambda\frac{x^2}{y}).$$ Now, I am trying to see what is the infimum and when it is achieved. I was wondering if any could help me computing this or give some general guidelines how to go about this, I always get stuck in this part of problems like this. Thanks!

Comment: The function you want to minimize is independent of y... For any $x$, you can find a $y$ such that the restraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are minimizing $e^{-x}$ which does not depend on $y$, so your constraint does not impose any restrictions, just pick any $y \le 0$, and minimum $e^{-x}$, which has a minimum of $0$ as $x \to \infty$...

Comment: But I am minimizing the whole expression $\inf_{x,y>0}(e^{-x}+\lambda \frac{x^2}{y})$, in that case the function I am minimizing does depend on y, right? Maybe that was not clear from the text, I corrected. If you're comment is still correct, why is it that the function doesn't depend on y, I don't quite see it.

Comment: @user110320 You can see it straight from the original problem, without the dual function. With the dual function, you minimize $e^{-x}$ component separately, and then pick $\lambda$ and $y$ to optimize the second component...